# Windows 10 search issue

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, windows-search, bug

It seems kinda like bug, let me explain.

I occasionally use search feature and don't like search bar, so I got used to *Win+S* hotkey combination. Normally, it would open Search box like small window on top of the taskbar, much like if you press Win button (opens Start menu) and then start typing (opens Search window).

But sometimes, when I press *Win+S* at the same time, the Search box opens on the whole left half of the screen, while the rest half of the screen is just black.

Since it opens up sometimes like that/sometimes like this, without specific conditions, I suspect it's much like a bug. Or is it?

Comment: Can you disable the shortcut you use, restart, check Search from the task bar and after that try the Shortcut again. Search works natively here on two Windows 10 Pro machines and 1 Windows 11 Pro machine.

Comment: I don't use the shortcut, I use default hotkey combination. I don't think I can somehow disable it.

Comment: Win S is working fine here (I was in Kali and Win S didn't do anything but back in Windows it works just right) - any machine I tried. I will keep looking but it appears to need a deeper repair (Windows 10 Repair Install).